# mysql 8 information_schema.processlist -> correct approach to cache it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a high concurrency mysql 8.0 server.
Thousands of tasks happen per second (up to a million rows per second read in average)

In some of the tasks that can be very performance intense I have an emergency switch to prevent the database queue from overflowing.

I read the number of processes (sometimes specific ones) from information_schema.processlist and if they exceed a certain value the task is skipped until the database is back in time.

So much so good, that worked perfectly fine in mysql 5.7 and before, but in mysql 8.0 they removed the query cache which might be the reason why it can not deliver such performance anymore.
In my case the server quickly is overflown with these SELECTS.

So I decided to run a background task that refreshes a table every second with a dump of the processlist.
I am using Innodb as MEMORY has more blocking issues.

This is the syntax I run every second:
processlist is "LIKE information_schema.processlist but I've changed the Info blob to a varchar"

```
BEGIN;
truncate table processlist;
replace into processlist SELECT ID,USER,HOST,DB,COMMAND,TIME,STATE,LEFT(INFO,1024) AS INFO FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE Command != 'Sleep';
COMMIT;
```

I am using a transaction to prevent race conditions and just truncate + replace into.

However I am not sure if this is the best solution to populate a "mirror" table.

So my question is: is this a good approach (especially not sure what truncate might  mean on performance) ? Any ideas how to do this better ?

Comment: `truncate table` a DDL statement, and isn't transactional. I suggest asking about your original problem. Are you using MySQL as a message queue (native implementations like rabbitmq are better)?

Comment: No, it's not good either for 5.7 or 8.0. Your better bet would be to monitor Threads_running from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and let the clients back off if it's too high.

Comment: Thanks for discovering and pointing out that the QC is the 'cause' of the significant slowdown.

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror table"

Comment: By "mirror" I meant a table that contains the same information as another table, a copy of it.   
In this case it's an innodb table 'processlist' that contains the same as information_schema.processlist.  
In my case it's not a complete copy because I use LEFT() to reduce the amount of data stored (some of my queries can be a few MB in size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I agree that `Threads_running` would be better.)

As for the Processlist, simply have a *single* program doing:

1. Collect processlist
2. parse and analyze it (there is probably no reason to have each worker do the same processing here)
3. store the minimal amount of info in some table dedicated to this purpose.  This is probably a single `UPDATE` statement.  (Not a much heavier `TRUNCATE`.)
4. Repeat forever -- Do *not* repeat every second; do it continually or with a slight delay in the loop.

The reason for *not* using a cron job:  When the server is too busy, you could get a new copy of the job starting before the first finishes.  It is *much* better to simply avoid that situation rather than use transactions (or whatever) to deal with it.

`MEMORY` should be fine, but might not be as fast as `InnoDB`.  The simple `UPDATE` is minimally invasive, so the storage engine should not matter much.

No transactions; minimal overhead.

Probably step 2 boils down to the equivalent of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';`

If it takes more effort to measure how "busy" the server is than to simple forge ahead, you are wasting your time.

(A side note:  `REPLACE` is worse than `INSERT` in this case -- `REPLACE` does a `DELETE`, but you have already `TRUNCATEd`!?)

Comment: The reason for the TRUNCATE is that I need to delete all entries from the processlist table as it's not self-delete like the original one from information_schema.
Do you think this transaction once per second is having any impact on the performance ? I mean it's a small table after all.  

I am not using a cron job, I use a background service that will not trigger the operation twice if the previous one is still loading.  

The truncate is only used because I have hundreds of threads accessing the table 'processlist', they should not access it empty between TRUNCATE and INSERT.

Comment: @John - I'm serious about not using truncate, and about doing the summarization in the background thread, and not using a timer to run it.  Without these changes, you have multiple problems waiting to happen.  Boil the processlist down to a single row of info; don't list the details.  (Or justify why you need multiple rows.)

Comment: Like I said, the timer I am using is preventing simultaneous executions.  
I might go for a single number instead, with the current approach I have the possibility to select for specific States and not just the whole count.  

For example I can look for locked rows, rows that are sending data, etc.

Comment: @John - A timer does _not_ prevent simultaneous executions.  If one invocation is severely delayed, it _really can_ bump into the next invocation.

Comment: It's a background task which only executes if the previous execution is finished, it will not execute twice. That really works fine.

Comment: I've filed a bug report, I noticed that the problem is not TRUNCATE or the transaction.  A simple query to the information_schema.processlist is choking the server.  If it's done once per second the performance is about 1/3 of normal. Once per 10 seconds still has a noticeable impact.  I am using your "show global status" now

Comment: @John - Unless you are using MySQL 8.0, many I_S queries have to do some hard work.  Perhaps it would sometimes take more than 1 second?  (I'll eventually convince you not to use cron/Events.)  An alternative to status (though probably same speed):  `SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_running';`

Comment: I'm not using cron, I use a multithreaded background service.
Whatever Mysql 8 is doing when listing processes, it's something that locks/delays tasks on a global context.
The query to list the processlist takes about 0.09 seconds (quite long indeed). However the whole server stalls shortly when it is done.  I could not "nail" it to a specific thing, it seems almost every sort of query is affected.    

I am not sure if "show status" is much better, it probably is but I'll have to benchmark it.

Comment: @John - In the deep recesses of my memory, I think I heard of some Mutex being grabbed by Processlist, and it was potentially as invasive as what you describe.  Grabbing global status (either way) is not free, but should be cheaper.